# DDOS attacks computer networks

Tags: networking, ddos

Is it possible for a ddos attacker to attack a computer behind a NAT(network address translator) as he is already shielded by an inside unique ip address ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless the router has a port forward to the server under attack.

Comment: server as in one who is attacking ?

Comment: No, the server being attacked, the one behind the router.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible your port address and NAT IP Address is also modified in spoofing attack so your web site are easily attack.

Answer (score 0):

if there s any way to get your packets to the server that you attend to attack, it s then possibly. For example, if that server is offering any kind of services(http server......).

Answer (score 0):

Before DDoS attack starts, the attacker will scan your network. He will attack the address and port he got the answer from.